# KeyStore.setKeyEntry returns NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: openssl, android-keystore

This question is addition to my previous question [How to import RSA private key, which generated by openssl, into AndroidKeyStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794576/how-to-import-rsa-private-key-which-generated-by-openssl-into-androidkeystore). I try to import my privateKey in KeyStore by the following way:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
ks.load(null);
ks.setKeyEntry("myAlias", prKey, null, new Certificate[] {cert});
```

and I get an exception:

```
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array"
```

And it is strange, because

1. `prKey.getAlgorithm()` return correct algorithm.
2. `cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm()` also return correct algorithm.
3. `ks.size()` works correctly.

Key and Certificate were generated by:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days XXX
openssl x509 -outform der -in cert.pem -out certificate.der
xxd -p certificate.der
```

So, think all parameters are correct, but why is it throw the exception?

Comment: * Please provide a full stack trace, including cause stack traces.
* Please provide the code illustrating how the PrivateKey instance being imported was obtained.

Comment: I've noticed there are some weird interactions with the Android KeyStore on occassion. For example, [AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey cannot be cast to RSAPrivateKey](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36305043) and [Crash casting AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey to RSAPrivateKey](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32400689).

Comment: > "Please provide a full stack trace, including cause stack traces".
thank you for support, but I cannot insert stack trace.